# How do you remove a file from your git database after moving it into LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I had some large files that were accidentally tracked in git. I didn't realize until many commits later. I moved those files into git LFS, but now I would like to delete them out of my normal git database as their deltas are taking up a huge amount of space.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that all solutions are history rewrites, which will require a level of coordination with everyone who has a clone of the repo to avoid your work being undone.

Three tools that can handle this, each with pros and cons:

The most specialized to your purpose would be `lfs migrate`.  https://github.com/bozaro/git-lfs-migrate

Another option would be BFG.  In my experience it does some things a little better, and others not as well, compared with lfs-migrate.  It also has the option to just rip the big files out without substituting in pointer files, if you don't care about breaking the history.  https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Or if you want to stick to git built-in commands, there's `git filter-branch` (but it will be slower and harder).  You could set up an `index-filter` to `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch` the affected paths (if they don't move around).  This might be slow and will break the affected commits.  You could instead use a `tree-filter` that replaces the affected paths with the appropriate pointer files and inserts a suitable `.gitattributes` file.  This is even slower (and potentially harder to get right.)